# Difference between USB bus vs port vs device vs interface

Tags: usb, lsusb

In the output of the lsusb -t command in Ubuntu, what is the difference between USB bus vs port vs device vs interface?

[image]

Edit: I found this [website](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml) very useful.

Comment: I voted to close this as off topic, it is not related to Ubuntu, seems generic, but this may help http://www.linux-usb.org/FAQ.html#i6

Answer (score 1):

The bus is which bus on the motherboard it is attached to.

The port is the port slot on your system.  The device number is the number assigned on that specific bus.

You can get more information on each device using

```
lsusb -v
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining port a bit more for me? Does this refer to the female USB port on either my desktop or laptop?